# Table values will not change with this Update query . No error is displayed and values remain the same

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to update my tables using this query. Once I hit 'update' im redirected to the view all page and all values remains the same. No change takes place but Not getting an error either. Please Help!

$sql = "UPDATE   myaddressbook.contacts SET (firstName,lastName,nickName,cellNumber,homeNumber,workNumber) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$nickName','$cellNumber','$homeNumber','$workNumber') " ; "UPDATE address SET(street,city,state,country) VALUES('$street','$city','$state','$country')"; "UPDATE  contacts SET (email,birthday,memo)
     VALUES ('$email','$birthday','$memo')  id = '{$_REQUEST['id']}'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are little bit off. Update queries use `UPDATE [table] SET [column] = [value], [column] = [value] ... WHERE [condition], [condition] ...` syntax, and it looks like you've confused that with INSERT syntax, which is `INSERT INTO [table] ([column], [column], ...) VALUES ([value], [value], ...);`

Try the following (hopefully it gives you a good idea of how to rewrite it):

```
UPDATE myaddressbook.contacts 
   SET firstName = '$firstName', lastName = '$lastName', ... 
   WHERE id = '$_REQUEST["id"]'
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Do I use UPDATE again when moving to the other table in the same query?

Comment: Use UPDATE queries if you're overwriting cells in a database, and INSERT queries if you're adding new ones.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE does not use VALUES -- it should be formed like this...

`UPDATE your_table_name SET your_field='your_value' WHERE ID='the_myself_id'`

(where ID = is a unique identifier column for the table)